# Is it impossible to pull a database file from non debuggable app in a non rooted device?

Tags: adb, permissions, sqlite

Here's what I tried:

- `adb shell "run-as my.package ..."` doesn't work because the app was installed without the `android:debuggable` option.
- `adb backup` doesn't work (it produces an empty file)
- I can't use the app to copy the database to sdcard, since I'm using a new computer which has a different signature (then, AndroidStudio asks to reinstall the app)

Do I have any option to extract the database?

Comment: You need to root your device or at least create a [NANDroid Backup](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/NANDroid)

Comment: Impossible without rooting.